# Can liquid nuclear fuel be injected and ignited like petro from a fuel injector?

Tags: space-travel, nuclear-power, gas, interstellar-travel, lasers

[image]

[![enter image description here][5]][5]

*Model Lightcraft under laser power*

While sadly the funding for this research has not been forthcoming, there have been [proof of principle flights](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5_9ac-w4DW8) and [open air flights](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LAdj6vpYppA), so this does work. (more about this [here](https://www.technologyreview.com/s/414629/riding-an-energy-beam-to-space/))

https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/103431/27786

Using the same method, could lasers or protons be beamed from a space stations or ground be used to detonate nuclear gas/dust/fuel injected from ports into the thrust chamber. Similar to a piston engine the chamber would fill and then detonated but many times a second?

[image]

Comment: You've [got a thing](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/102865/) for tiny nuclear explosions. What is a "proton beam"? (Hint: all protons are positively charged, and like charges repel.) What is "nuclear gas/dust/fuel"?

Comment: *sadly the funding for this research has not been forthcoming* Thank you for restoring my faith in grant committees (a little). :-)

Comment: Nuclear "stuff" doesn't just explode - it isn't inherently explosive.You can't just burn the stuff and expect it to go boom, unfortunately. Nuclear explosions happen either because the specific Fission or Fusion process releases vast amounts of energy. Fission basically means that the atoms change into smaller atoms whilst fusion means the atoms fuse into bigger atoms - both processes releasing large amounts of energy.

Comment: To expand, For nuclear fission weapons you usually have two pieces of nuclear material being smashed together at high speed, whereas for fission power generation its two pieces of nuclear material being held close together to heat water, which is then used in a steam turbine. I'm not sure of the physics behind fusion but I believe weapons basically have extra knobs and whistles to create the fusion reaction, whilst nuclear power generation via fusion is still in its early stages and currently requires far more power to generate the reaction than it creates.

Comment: This is not a worldbuilding question, it's a physics question better asked as [Physics.SE](http://physics.stackexchange.com).  And, for the record, Mr. Myrabo's idea is fascinating from the perspective of pushing somthing through an atmosphere in a straight line.  It works **because** you don't need to haul the fuel with you.  Anything's better once you're required to make space for the fuel.

Comment: This concept is somewhat similar to inertial confinement fusion (ICF) applied to space propulsion. This would be tricky for interstellar travel especially if the laser beam is external to the spacecraft. One of those ideas that sounds fine in principle, but mindbogglingly difficult to implement practically.

Comment: I don't think this is answerable. As you said, research needed to figure out if this works was abandoned. If scientists can't figure this s out, how could we?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Why bother?

If you're going to take fuel into space (the fuel [being literally 80% of a space craft's weight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propellant_mass_fraction) or more) what's the point of leaving the ignition source on the ground? Combustible fuel burns Just Fine without a laser, ignition is cheap. The same goes for nukes.

Lasers work for an air-based craft because the laser (i.e. the power source) remains on the ground and turns the ambient air (free!) into plasma, which provides thrust.

In space, **there is no air.** Because there is no air, you get nothing for free.

The only way you can use a ground-based laser to propel a ship through space is if the ship weighs virtually nothing and has a very large [light sail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_sail). Photons DO carry a very small amount of thrust capability to them, but you need trillions upon trillions of them to get an appreciable thrust.

It's called a [photonic laser thruster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photonic_laser_thruster) and it works by bouncing light between two mirrors. You can get a whopping 3.5 millinewtons with a 500 W laser. You need 5,000,000,000 newtons (roughly) to achieve escape velocity from Earth. That's 1,000,000,000,000 (one trillion) times as much power input needed which is on the scale of [the most powerful laser ever built](https://www.popsci.com/researchers-japan-fired-worlds-most-powerful-laser) (and its still only half as much power as we'd need).

Comment: It would save weight. Constant mini nuclear explosions to produce thrust without the need of oxygen. More bang per buck. +1

Comment: @Muze It would save like, a dozen kilograms of weight, on a hundred thousand dry weight craft. Its literally a drop.

Comment: Think bigger like the bottom of a ship..Much of the power would be provided remotely saving more on board power.. What else would  be comparable in bang per once?

Comment: @Muze Providing power from the ground does not work in space like this. you want a laser to propel your ship, you need a light sail

Comment: @Muze, I strongly suggest you read up on [Project Orion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_(nuclear_propulsion)) if you're interested in the use of nuclear reactions for explosive propulsion.

Comment: The Myrabo lightship works in space, you simply carry a reaction mass and inject it into the space where the annular mirror reflects and focuses the beam. You can use water because it is cheap and simple (although Hydrogen provides the best ISP). Like any rocket, it does rely on ejecting reaction mass at high speed, so there are limitations based on the amount of reaction mass you are able to carry. Still, if you launch using air as the reaction mass, then everything in the tank is free and clear once you are in space, you did not need to use any of it.